# How to access to product and attributes when writing a cron in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, cron

I need to write a cron which will check for some product attribute/states.

I'm new to Magento, and I guess the best way to do it is to use the provided Magento method.

So how does Cron works within magento?

As far I know, there are module the same as used everywhere, which are then run by the Cron.

Do you have any exemple on how to write a cron for Magento and use the Magento methods to iterate through products/attributes?

Comment: what will you do after check? please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this links can reference for you...

http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/07/how-to-schedule-the-future-product-activation.html
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/